# Handle a B model inside the view's form of an A model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a classic `form_for`:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Modèle" %>
    <%= f.text_field :model, required: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Immatriculation" %>
    <%= f.text_field :license_plate, required: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Complément" %>
    <%= f.text_field :complement, required: true%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Puissance CV" %>
    <%= f.number_field :horse_power, required: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Indemnité KM" %>
    <%= f.number_field :km_compensation, required: true%>
  </div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit 'Sauvegarder' %>
</div>
```

I would like to use another model inside this view, that would also update when the user clicks the submit button. I know this has to do with `nested forms` but I'm a little confused about how to implement it. Here's the variable from the second model that I would like to add:

```
<% @trip_distances.each do |t| %>
  <%= form_for(t) do |e| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= e.text_field t.id_contract %>
        <%= e.number_field t.length %>
      </div>
 <% end %>
```

Obviously this is not correct. I guess I need to use the `field_for` method?

Comment: You need fields_for and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810158/rails-4-child-record-id-is-saved-but-not-its-attributes-using-nested-form-with/27810187#27810187

Comment: Yes, check http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, consider using [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), as it cleans up a bit the code, and is overall more developer-friendly :)

Then in your view you will have something like

```
<%= simple_form_for sth do |form| %>
  <% form.input :attributeUno %>
  <% form.input :length %>
 ...
```

Then to add to this form inputs for nested element add [simple_fields_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#simple-fields-for)

```
<% @trip_distances.each do |t|
  <%= form.simple_fields_for t do |fields| %>
    <% fields.input :length %>
    ...
```

And don't forget to add

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :something` in your model :)

PS: You should also consider using [slim](http://slim-lang.com) or [haml](http://haml.info/) to make creating views a bit easier, and also clean them up :)